# moving a html element during swipe with chriswessels:hammer

Tags: meteor, hammer.js

This meteor client code uses `chriswessels:hammer@4.0.2`
, the `swipeleft` works by invoking `console.log('moved left')` but how can I get the html element to actually move with the finger? Thanks

```js
Template.swipe.helpers({
  'configureHammer': function() {
    return function(hammer, templateInstance) {
      let swipeleft = new Hammer.Swipe({
        event: 'swipeleft',
        pointers: 1,
        velocity: 0.2
      });
      hammer.add(swipeleft);
      return hammer;
    }
  },
  'swipeGestures': {
    'swipeleft .swipe': function(event, templateInstance) {
      console.log('moved left');
    }
  }
});
```